# ruby confusing -- local variable or instance_method?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have the following program.

```
module C
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)

  end

  module ClassMethods
    def test_for
      class_eval <<-DEFINECLASSMETHODS
        def self.my_method(param_a)
          puts "SELF is: #{self.inspect}"
          puts param_a
          puts "#{param_a}"
        end
      DEFINECLASSMETHODS
    end
  end
end

class A
  include C
end

class B < A
  test_for
end
```

when I run `B.new.my_method("aaa")`, I got this error

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `param_a' for B:Class
```

I am quite confused.

I define param_a as a local variable in class method my_method,

```
puts param_a
```

runs good, and will output the "aaa".

however,

```
puts "#{param_a}"
```

output that error.

why?

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are some majorly complex hoops you are jumping through, to achieve basically this:

```
module C
  def test_for
    define_singleton_method :my_method do |param_a|
      puts "SELF is: #{inspect}"
      p param_a
    end
  end
end

class A
  extend C
end

class B < A
  test_for
end

B.my_method 'foo'
# => SELF is: B
# => "foo"
```

EDIT: I just realized that the solution above is *still* much more complicated than it needs to be. In fact, we do not need any metaprogramming *at all*:

```
module C
  module D
    def my_method(param_a)
      puts "SELF is: #{inspect}"
      p param_a
    end
  end
  def test_for
    extend D
  end
end

class A
  extend C
end

class B < A
  test_for
end

B.my_method 'foo'
# => SELF is: B
# => "foo"
```

Answer (score 3):

You get that error because the `#{}` doesn't interpolate param_a into the string passed to puts - it interpolates it into the string passed to class_eval. It will work when you escape it, i.e.

```
puts "\#{param_a}"
```

You can also disable interpolation inside the heredoc by using `<<-'DEFINECLASSMETHODS'` instead of `<<-DEFINECLASSMETHODS`. This will also allow you to use other meta characters without having to escape them.

Comment: Damn! I totally missed that! +1 for eagle-eyes! Personally, I have the rule that I *always* use single-quoted strings, unless I am 100% sure that I absolutely, positively *want* string interpolation to occur. This is just one more example why that is a good idea.

Comment: This is one of the many reasons why I always recommend using the block form of `class_eval`.

Answer (score 2):

Try using "class_eval do; end" instead, like this:

```
def test_for
  class_eval do
    def self.my_method(param_a)
      puts "SELF is: #{self.inspect}"
      puts param_a
      puts "#{param_a}"
    end 
  end 
end
```

This way, no code escaping is necessary.